# 1 - sum of probabilities for mutually exclusive?

Tags: probability

For mutually exclusive events `A,B,C,D`, I am wondering about

$$1 - (P(A) + P(B) + P(C) + P(D))$$

Normally, $P(A) + P(B) + P(C) + P(D)$ means the probability that any of the events $A,B,C,D$ occur since they are mutually exclusive, but does the same apply for the 1 - sum formula?

Comment: Yes......................................................................................

Comment: @herbsteinberg so does it means the probability that NEITHER $A,B,C,D$ will occur?

Comment: yes.  Apparently you are just learning basic probability.

Answer (score 0):

Define $X$ to be the event that at least one of $A,B,C,D$ occur. Since $A,B,C,D$ are mutually exclusive, $P(X)=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)+P(D)$

Then $1-(\;P(A)+P(B)+P(C)+P(D)\;)=1-P(X)=P(X')$, where $X'$ is the compliment of $X$, that is, $P(X')$ is the probability that none of the events $A,B,C,D$ occur. You intuition is correct.